# How numpy broadcasting works?

Tags: python, numpy

How `numpy` broadcasting works?

My understanding:

two arrays

```
one = np.random.rand(3,2)
two = np.random.rand(5,10)
```

in order to subtract each entry of array `one` by array `two`, each entry of array `one` must first be converted to a 2d array by something like

```
one_expanded = one[...,None,None]
```

then, `one_expanded` can directly subtract `two` to get the expected result.

However, I cannot comprehend how `numpy` actually works in the following two examples based on my understanding.

**Example 1**

```
one = np.random.rand(3,2,1)
two = np.random.rand(2,10)
(one-two).shape
```

**Example 2**

```
one = np.random.rand(3,2,2,1)
two = np.random.rand(1,2,2,10)
(one-two).shape
```

Actually, I use the syntax in Example 2 a lot, but I rarely think of how it works as long as the output is correct.

What is the correct way of picturing `numpy` broadcasting?

Comment: There is a very detailed explanation of this in the docs. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html. Please research before asking. SO is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add two arrays, element-wise addition happens. That is only possible when the shape exactly matches. When does broadcasting occur?

Consider there are *N* dimensions in your arrays. That is, `array.shape` produces a N-tuple. If *m* out of *N* dimensions match for the two arrays to be added together, and any one of those arrays has rest of the shape values (*N-m*) as *1*, `numpy` automatically expands these dimensions to match the corresponding dimensions in the other array.

Consider *Example 2* in your Q. The shapes are `(3,2,2,1)` and `(1,2,2,10)`. Hence, the two dimensions in middle are of matching sizes. For the first dimension, however, the first array has the value *3* and the second, *1*. This matches the case we described and hence fits the criterion of broadcasting. The second array, hence, will be repeated thrice along the first dimension when adding, which will allow the dimensions to match. Similarly for the last dimension.

Also, always read the docs. Here's the official article on [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).